# Посчитать пустые элементы массива

Tags: php

есть массив примерного вида

```
[1] => 32
[2] => 
[3] => 42
[4] => 
[5] => 
[6] => 
[7] => 
[8] => 36
[9] => 42
```

необходимо посчитать количество пустых элементов массива.
я соответственно пробовал переберать

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
   if($array[$i] == ""){
     $temp ++;
   }
}
```

однако он что то не то выводит. подскажите дураку куда чего?)

Comment: До конца не уверен что нужно именно это, поэтому комментарием.

`$mockArray = array(1 => 1, 2, 3, 9 => 9);
$mockArray[4] = null;
$mockArray[5] = null;
$counter = 0;
foreach ($mockArray as $key => $item) {
    if ($item === null)
        $counter++;
}
var_dump($counter);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $item){
  if(empty($item)){ 
    $i++;
  }
}
```

Код на [`ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/MgM6J6)

Comment: спасибо , однако он счиатет только до следующего попадания на НЕ пустой элемент масива

Comment: @Михаил2342 - что? Я не понял, что вы хотите этим сказать. Приведите, пожалуйста, пример массива на котором этот цикл работает неправильно.

Comment: [1] => 32
[2] => ""
[3] => 42
[4] => ""
[5] => ""

к примеру в таком случае, $i будет равен 1.

Comment: @Михаил2342 - [Неправда][1]

[1]: http://ideone.com/iDtKDT

Comment: да, извиняюсь, была ошибка в заполнении массива. спасибо.